# How to create a custom module structure in Android Studio

Tags: android, android-studio

I am not really sure if it is possible, but here is what I would like to do. Currently Android Studio allows you to create custom templates and when creating new file you can use that template.

I would like to do the same thing but with modules, for example I want to make a "module template" so every time I create a module it generates the full structure of folders/packages/files that I have set in my "module template". There are different module templates currently in Android Studio that are there by default, but I could not find if I can create one myself.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can perform any process you want by using [Generate Module From Template](https://plugins.jetbrains.com/plugin/13586-generate-module-from-template).

[image: Generate Module From Template]

Comment: That's pretty nice plugin, thanks for sharing it does exactly what I wanted. Hopefully they also add native to android also, like the file templates.

Comment: I hope it will be added in the future.